# How to insert JSON file data to SQL Server table using sql command

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I am not so familiar with SQL.

I have a table in my SQL Server database called `Product`

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Product] (
[Age]          INT           NULL,
[Name]         NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
[Id]           NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
[Price]        DECIMAL (18)  NULL,
[ImageUrl]     NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
[Snippet]      NVARCHAR (50) NULL
)
```

I have a JSON file (which locates in `D:\demo\myjson.json`) where stores all my product info like:

```
[
  {
      "Age": 0, 
      "Id": "motorola-xoom-with-wi-fi", 
      "ImageUrl": "static/imgs/phones/motorola-xoom-with-wi-fi.0.jpg", 
      "Name": "Motorola XOOM\u2122 with Wi-Fi", 
      "Price":5000,
      "Snippet": "The Next, Next Generation\r\n\r\nExperience the future with Motorola XOOM with Wi-Fi, the world's first tablet powered by Android 3.0 (Honeycomb)."
  }, 
  {
      "Age": 1, 
      "Id": "motorola-xoom", 
      "ImageUrl": "static/imgs/phones/motorola-xoom.0.jpg", 
      "Name": "MOTOROLA XOOM\u2122", 
      "Price":5000,
      "Snippet": "The Next, Next Generation\n\nExperience the future with MOTOROLA XOOM, the world's first tablet powered by Android 3.0 (Honeycomb)."
  }

]
```

How can I write sql to get this file and import data into my `Product` table instead of manually doing this?

I am using SQL Server 2016 and SSMS.

Comment: I suggest changing the [Snippet] column to NVARCHAR(MAX) from NVARCHAR(50) by looking at your data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try an approach, which uses `OPENROWSET()` (to read the file) and `OPENJSON()` with explicit schema (to parse the input JSON).

Note, that `OPENROWSET()` needs additional [permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openrowset-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#permissions) (*... OPENROWSET permissions are determined by the permissions of the user name that is being passed to the OLE DB provider. To use the BULK option requires ADMINISTER BULK OPERATIONS or ADMINISTER DATABASE BULK OPERATIONS permission. ...*). Also, if the file contains unicode input you should use `SINGLE_NCLOB` modifier.

```
DECLARE @json nvarchar(max)

SELECT @json = BulkColumn
FROM OPENROWSET (BULK 'D:\demo\myjson.json', SINGLE_NCLOB) as j

INSERT INTO [Product] ([Age], [Name], [Id], [Price], [ImageUrl], [Snippet])
SELECT [Age], [Name], [Id], [Price], [ImageUrl], [Snippet]
FROM OPENJSON(@json) WITH (
   Age int '$.Age',
   Name nvarchar(50) '$.Name',
   Id nvarchar(50) '$.Id',
   ImageUrl nvarchar(50) '$.ImageUrl',
   Price decimal(18) '$.Price',
   Snippet nvarchar(50) '$.Snippet'
)
```

Comment: Ok,I manage to make it work now.Thank you very much.A little more question is that I add wrong data at first and there are all `null` values in columns but I could not delete it...See [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQnPD.png）, do you know how to handle it？

Comment: @XingZou If you want to delete all rows with `NULL` values, you should use a statement like `DELETE [Product] WHERE (Age IS NULL) AND (Name IS NULL) AND (Id IS NULL) AND (Price IS NULL) ... (all columns here)`.

Comment: Work,but I do not know why I could not just delete all column by selecting these rows and right-click to choose delete option...anyway, thanks again